# Why aren't custom variables working with user-timings api?

Tags: google-analytics

I am setting multiple custom variables in my single page application. They are able to be used as a segment or as a secondary dimension in pretty much everywhere in the analytics dashboard: "Audience", "Events", and even within "Site Speed - Page Timings".

However, if I try to use these custom variables to segment my data when using "Site Speed - User Timings", it acts as if nothing has ever been recorded with that custom variable associated with it.

I know that it isn't that only page-load-associated metrics like Page Timing and Audience are being successfully associated with the custom variables, because it is working fine for Events. I see no reason why this wouldn't be working. Documentation says nothing about User Timings being incompatible with custom variables.

Has anyone run into this issue before? Is this an undocumented incompatibility or should I continue to look for an implementation bug?

Comment: Can you post the tracking code you are using.  Sounds to me like you aren't sending the custom vars when you are sending the user Timings.   Only other idea I have is that the website cant handle it, and you should check the data via the API directly.  The documentation says that custom dimensions are compatible with all hit types I checked that first :)